# Determining scale issues covariance

Tags: covariance, boxplot

**Background for Question**

A tibble: 6 x 4

[image]

This was given to us. I produced a **bivariate/matrix **scatterplot**** using pairs command and got the following (as well as a **boxplot**):

[image]

[image]

**QUESTION: Could scale be an issue when determining covariance?**

I know covariance is sensitive to outliers and measures LINEAR ASSOCIATION. And using the article [Baffled by Covariance and Correlation???](https://towardsdatascience.com/let-us-understand-the-correlation-matrix-and-covariance-matrix-d42e6b643c22), it seems TRUE.

Am I thinking on the right track?

**MY ANSWER:**

Looking at the boxplots of sales, profit and assets, we notice a large variability in assets, whereas profits have the smallest variability. Since, the scale of the three variables (sales, profit and assets) differ significantly, the scale could be an issue in computing covariance (referenced) as covariance involves the product of measuring the spread (i.e `xij - x_bari`) and (`xjk - x_bark`).